# ActiveRecord: Different representations of a model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, inheritance, activerecord, mixins

I have a model named Book which represents a book with all available data. I need now specialization of the book instance for several cases (just examples):

- An AmazonBook has an id from the asin (amazon standard identification number) or the isbn (depending on which is available, asin is prefered). It also has a specific csv-version of a book record. The "special-attribute" asin is included in the basic book-record.
- Books on other marketplaces need other (virtual?) attributes, for example a csv-export to the Booklooker-marketplace has a different structure, or the Booklooker-Marketplace has own "special-attributes". These special-attributes are all stored in the basic book-record

The specialized instance always refers to the same book-record in the database, for example the record has a asin AND a special booklooker-attribute or whatever. I did this for speed, to avoid join-operations (around 200000 records in the database).

What ist the right way to implement this? Inheritance (AmazonBook < Book, BooklookerBook < Book, ...) or non-ActiveRecord classes, with initializers that get the book instance) or ...??

I'd like to get my code more structured, at the moment I have a fat model class with methods like amazon_id, amazon_csv, other_id, other_csv, ...
I'd like to have an accessor like @book.amazon.to_csv or @book.booklooker.csv to access different representations in the same view. Two different instances @amazon_book and @booklooker_book which are in fact the same book are not the way to go I think...

Maybe a kind of api is the solution? Or a kind of "method namespacing"?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Maybe this is one of the rare situations to use single table inheritance. http://samurails.com/tutorial/single-table-inheritance-with-rails-4-part-1/

Comment: That doesn't hit the problem. A book is an AmazonBook AND a BooklookerBook at the same time. With STI every subtype has it's own book-record.
With subtypes in your example: a Lion also has to be a Meerkat, it has to be able to have both behaviours according to the current use case.

Comment: Ah, okay so that really dosen't hit the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Create a number of models with has_one relationships to Book.

```
Amazon_Book 
  belongs_to :book

Booklover_Book
  belongs_to :book

Book
  has_one :amazon_book
  has_one :booklover_book
```

Then your desired accessors will work

```
book = Book.find(...)
book.amazon_book.asin 
book.booklover_book.whatever
```

You can add, modify, and delete your market-specific models without affecting the overall Book model, or each other.